# Put a video at a specific location

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, video

How do I anchor a video at a specific location in a page of beamer? I use the following codes but do not know how to control the location. I want to put the video in the right half of the page and in the middle of the page vertically. Please help.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=south west, inner sep=0pt] at (current page.south west) {%
    \includemedia[
    addresource=video.mp4,
    activate=pageopen,transparent,
    flashvars={source=video.mp4},
    %flashvars={source=DRS2.mp4},
    width=\paperwidth+1in ,height=\paperheight
    ]{}{VPlayer.swf}%
};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: You are using `current page.south west`. Why don't you use `[xshift=.25\paperwidth]current page.center`?

Comment: Thanks, @TeXnician. This is exactly what I am looking for. I changed the node to \node[anchor=center, inner sep=0pt] at ([xshift=.25\paperwidth]current page.center) and get what I need. Thank again!

Comment: I've posted it as answer. Feel free to accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a placement specification `current page.south west`, but you should use something like `[xshift=.25\paperwidth]current page.center`, which orients at center position, but shifts to a horizontally centered position within the right half of the page.

You also need to change your node anchor (`center` would be appropriate).